# Problems reading data from Arduino over rs485

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, rs485

I have written a small program to communicate between RasPi and Arduino. I can send messages from the RasPi to the Arduino perfectly. The Arduino will read the incoming message, and respond appropriately. The problem occurs when the RasPi is reading the Arduino message.

The arduino is sending "2, 2, 'A', 'B', 'C', (crc)". I can confirm that by attaching a second arduino onto the rs485 network. Python reads this as random gibberish, and gives me this:

```
b'\xd5'
b'i'
b'\x8a'
b'j'
b'z'
b'\xf6'
b'T'
b'{'
b'\xf6'
b'\x8c'
b'\xe2'
b'\xfe'
```

Python Code (not the entire code, just what is relevant):

```
data = bytearray()
info = ord('A')
data.append(info)

sendMsg(2, len(data), data)
while(True):
  inByte = rs.read()
  print(inByte)
```

Comment: Either you have a hardware problem or mistmatch in baud rate. How have you wired and set the port up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode data.

Try

```
inByte = rs.read().decode('utf-8')
```